# How to add text to a disabled Tkinter Text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, text-widget

I'm aware of the fact that text widgets are disabled using `widget.config(state = tk.DISABLED)`, making the user unable to change the content of the widget. Content can be added before this statement is run using `widget.insert(tk.END, text-to-add)`, but after that you'd have to alternate between the `NORMAL` and `DISABLED` states to add text content, using a command like this:

```py
def add_text(widget, text):
   widget.config (state = tk.NORMAL)
   widget.insert (tk.END, text)
   widget.config (state = tk.DISABLED)
```

Is there any other, more efficient way to do that?

Comment: That's all you can do with a text widget, from tk's documentation: "Specifies one of two states for the text: normal or disabled. If the text is disabled then characters may not be inserted or deleted and no insertion cursor will be displayed, even if the input focus is in the widget." http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/text.htm#M17

Comment: Seems lik you could workaround the fact that can't do inserts when the widget is disabled by "batching" a bunch of successive ones up and then inserting all that are pending just before enabling for real later (which is presumably the intention of changing it).

Comment: If the Entry is linked to a StringVar updating the StringVar updates the displayed text whether the Entry is normal or disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any other, more efficient way to do that?

No, there is not. That is the most efficient way to do what you want.